# How to override a mongoose model?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to render a mongoose model dynamically and editing the fields via a UI, therefore i need to override a mongoose model. i am getting the following error:

```
OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `[MODEL NAME]` model once compiled.
```

If i delete the schema property and model objects

```
for (modelName in that.innstance.models) {
    // deletes the mongoose models and schema
    delete mongoose.models[modelName];
    delete mongoose.modelSchemas[modelName];

    delete app.models[modelName];
}
```

I am able to register the model again, however when i create from that a model object i cam only access the properties via **MODEL._doc.some_field** and not **MODEL.some_field**

Comment: Why not compile the model as soon as you know what is going to be in it?

Comment: it is dynamic. i need to be able to change it on the fly.

Comment: @AryehArmon as you've already noticed, Mongoose isn't really the right tool for such a job (although I wouldn't directly know an alternative).

Comment: Don't use a mapper if you wouldn't be able to have semi-consistent data anyway. Good old `mongo` package.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the way i did it was good,
there was an issue when i reloaded my schemas that the right fields did not register. so it was not connected to what i did.

If anyone would like to override the models just deleting it will be the right way to go.